# Mac Gunzip Uncompress Failed Incomplete File

Tags: macos, terminal, gunzip

I've looked around on different posts and different sites and can't seem to find a working solution.

I have unfinished files (gunzip says unexpected end of file).

I've tried

```
gunzip -f output.txt.gz 
zcat doesn't work (not a Z file)
```

Any solutions?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] that allows us to reproduce the issue you are facing.

Comment: If the file is incomplete/damaged, you may not be able to extract anything from it. What happened to the file, and what are you trying to get from it?